# Python: MemoryError querying database with large number of records

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory

I've written the code below to cycle through data stored in influx db (a database). The data gets quite large so ive written a routine that plots the daily data and then moves onto the next day.   The query works fine for the first few days but then reports errors memory.  Any thoughts on how to solve this?

```
> 5 2019-07-17 2019-07-17
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-38-7e713c29e2f7> in <module>
>      17     date_to = day_with_data["to"] # assigns the value from pandas to varable
>      18     # runs the query and appends to list of dates
> ---> 19     data = (client.query("""SELECT "pressure" FROM "NoT/pressure" WHERE time >= """ + '\'' +
> date_from + start_time + '\'' + """ and time <= """ + '\'' + date_to +
> end_time + '\''))
>      20     # drops the columns to index
>      21     data = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
> 
> c:\program files
> (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\influxdb\_dataframe_client.py in
> query(self, query, params, epoch, expected_response_code, database,
> raise_errors, chunked, chunk_size, method, dropna)
>     180                           method=method,
>     181                           chunk_size=chunk_size)
> --> 182         results = super(DataFrameClient, self).query(query, **query_args)
>     183         if query.strip().upper().startswith("SELECT"):
>     184             if len(results) > 0:
> 
> c:\program files
> (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\influxdb\client.py in query(self,
> query, params, epoch, expected_response_code, database, raise_errors,
> chunked, chunk_size, method)
>     420             return self._read_chunked_response(response)
>     421 
> --> 422         data = response.json()
>     423 
>     424         results = [
> 
> c:\program files
> (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self,
> **kwargs)
>     887                 try:
>     888                     return complexjson.loads(
> --> 889                         self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs
>     890                     )
>     891                 except UnicodeDecodeError:
> 
> MemoryError:
```

The code below is the routine that ive written:

```
#Creates varible to store dataframes
list_of_dates = []

#creates the end time and start time for the influx query
start_time = 'T00:00:00Z'
end_time = "T23:59:59Z" 

#Creates a loop through all the values  
for index,day_with_data in list_of_all_days_with_data[5: 22].iterrows():
    print(index, day_with_data["from"],day_with_data["to"]) # prints the from dates 
    date_from  = day_with_data["from"] # assigns the value from pandas column to variable 
    date_to = day_with_data["to"] # assigns the value from pandas to variable 
    # runs the query and appends to list of dates 
    data = (client.query("""SELECT "pressure" FROM "NoT/pressure" WHERE time >= """ + '\'' + date_from + start_time + '\'' + """ and time <= """ + '\'' + date_to + end_time + '\''))
    # drops the columns to index 
    data = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
    data.columns = data.columns.droplevel()
    # this does work 
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.title("plot from " + date_from + " - " + date_to) # subplot 211 title
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Bars in pressure')
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [20, 20]
    file_name = date_from + " - " + date_to + ".png"
    plt.savefig(file_name)
    plt.show()


    time.sleep(10) # timer so i dont hog the influx db
```

Comment: You keep expanding a DataFrame on this line `data = pd.concat(data, axis=1)`. If you do this for a while, eventually you will run out of memory.

Comment: Are we expected to fix performance issues, a potentially complex task, without any data or even the complete program? D: Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `del data` after the `plt.show()` line.

I thought the reassigning on the line :

```
data = (client.query("""SELECT "pressure" FROM "NoT/pressure" WHERE time >= """ + '\'' + date_from + start_time + '\'' + """ and time <= """ + '\'' + date_to + end_time + '\''))
```

would blank the memory but forcing a delete did the trick.  Well you learn something everyday,